# viewWillAppear incorrect orientation when presentViewController without a navigation view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I came across a strange problem, i'am in landscape and present a VC

```
SomeViewController * vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

in the `viewWillAppear` **the frame is incorrectly in portrait** and in `viewDidAppear` it **is correctly in landscape**

but when i put it inside a UINavigationController

```
SomeViewController * vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController * nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

than in the `viewWillAppear` **the frame is correctly landscape**

**Is this a bug? I'am i missing something? Why it is behaving like this?**

Answer (score 0):

I think it is by design, see this answer [A: View frame changes between viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637998/1394020).

By `viewDidAppear` the frame geometry is correct since it is now on-screen and added to the view hierarchy but I would actually recommend doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` since that will be called when rotating orientations as well.