# Why does a table view header display correctly when added in viewWillLayoutSubviews and not in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm loading a table view header from a xib file and setting it like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ... // My header view.
```

The view loaded from the xib is already the correct size (300 x 50px). When I execute this code in the table view controller's `viewDidLoad` method the header appears with a height of 0px. When I set it in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, it appears with the correct height of 50px. In both cases the width is set to the correct width (634px).

I've seen lots of posts about setting the header height and I can get everything working fine by adding it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but what I have not found is an explanation of why it works in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and not `viewDidLoad`.

Does anyone know why?

As `viewDidLoad` is executed first, I would have thought adding the header there would be fine.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, the frames are not guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: In my case the header view contains internal constraints that will generate a height of 50px. The thing I don't understand is why setting the header in viewWillLayoutSubviews respects these constraints where as setting it earlier does not.

Comment: You have autolayout disabled?

Comment: Using `Autolayout`, frame of your views are set when the autolayout engine starts its calculation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638247/3207014

Comment: @drekka you half-answered yourself. viewDidLoad the view has not yet applied the constrains. This is why in the viewWillLayoutSubviews is the suggested place to make any modification to your views.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I'm not being clear or understanding what you guys are saying. I understand that layout is done in viewWillLayoutSubviews and not in viewDidLoad. I haven't disabled auto layout. I'm not doing anything with the frames or positioning. I'm merely setting the tableHeaderView property. What I don't understand is why If I set it in viewDidLoad, the height is zero'd when constraints are calculated later on. Even if I do a setNeedsLayout on the header after setting it. It's as if the only way to get the table view to use the height is to set the property in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I understand that viewWillLayoutSubviews is a place for modifying views. Especially sizes, constraints, etc. What I don't get is why adding a header view prior to that would cause the layout calculations to get it wrong.